# Oracle Forms Clear Record in When-Validate-Record Trigger

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

When user begin filling the record then they click other record before committing i want to clear the last record like it never filled.

So i create when-validate-record in data block as below:

```
begin
  if :MYBLOCK.SEQ is null then --if there is no seq yet, means its not committed
    Clear_Record;
  end if;
end;
```

**But** `clear_record` causes error that says `Invalid limited CLEAR_RECORD procedure` and usage seems correct to me. And i also tried `Clear_Record(no_validate)` but it also doesn't work. I saw some usage of `clear_record` and i can't get why it doesn't work. I could use some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricted procedures (not *limited*, as you put it) can't be called from all triggers; `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` being one of them.

One option you might choose is to interact with the user and tell them what to do. Still the `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` trigger:

```
if :MYBLOCK.SEQ is null then -- if there is no seq yet, means its not committed
   message('Save the record or - if you do not need it - delete it');
   raise form_trigger_failure;
end if;
```

Benefit of such an approach is that user (not the procedure in background) decides what to do. I wouldn't want to enter 20 fields on the screen, accidentally click one of previous records and lose everything I've done so far.

Comment: After this post, i faced with the same error in **item-validate** trigger on 'go_block' line and i've kinda realized your point bec its perfectly working in some other triggers. You're right, I'll talk to our project analyst and figure something out. Thank's clarifying the issue

Comment: You're welcome. Open Forms Online Help system and search for "restricted procedures"; they are well described there, I hope you'll find it useful.